# problem in auto_increment in mysql?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

iam getting a problem in auto increment that is . I declared auto increment and off set values as 5, 14 respectively in /etc/my.cnf file. and in creation of a table i declared auto increment.upto here every thing is fine. but wen iam ading a record it starts with 3 only.depending on auto_increment value the starting value in record is changing. it never starts with auto_increment value. please solve this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: on your create table statement, did you have AUTO_INCREMENT 14

Answer (score 1):

auto increment always accept the greater value than the maximum present value in your table

Answer (score 0):

run this query on your table and you can set where the auto increment starts:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 15;
```

or to any value you need

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you read your Auto-increment vars using:

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%'`

Do you get the Values you set before?

**notice that if the value of auto_increment_offset is greater than that of auto_increment_increment, the value of auto_increment_offset is ignored.**

Read the [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment)